# Hide / Show Content on Click & Change Image of Toggle, Multiple Occurrences On Same Page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script> function toggle5(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
    imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/vKhOkQy.png">';
    }
    else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/sqeimfN.png">';
    }       }

    
    

function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://i.imgur.com/vKhOkQy.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://i.imgur.com/sqeimfN.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://i.imgur.com/vKhOkQy.png";
    }
} </script>
```

Body:

```
<a href="javascript:toggle5('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');"><img  src="https://i.imgur.com/vKhOkQy.png" width="22px" 
        alt="Hide the Disclaimer"  style="vertical-align: top; " title="Hide the Disclaimer" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  /></a>
<div class="animatedParent animateOnce" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle ;">
<div id="contentDivImg" class="animated bounceInRight"  style="  margin:5px; width: 354px; display: none ">
  <div>Hidden Info<br>

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iHcZrbo.png" alt="Power Fists!"  style="vertical-align: top; " title="Power Fists!" />  

  </div>        
</div>
```

This works perfectly. It Hides & Shows Content on Click (of toggle image) & Change Image of Toggle.

But, i'm having trouble having Multiple Occurrences On the Same Page.

Comment: BTW, It only works properly when the images are on the internet and not a local drive. Also doesn't seem to work on online JS snippet viewer for some reason

Comment: Working Version (1 instance): https://justinwallis.com/hideshowscript/hideshowscript.html

Answer (score 0):

This is my (non working) code for when i try to have two items on the page that i want to act without effecting each other.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 


function toggle5(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
    imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/vKhOkQy.png">';
    }
    else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/sqeimfN.png">';
    } }
    

function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://i.imgur.com/vKhOkQy.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://i.imgur.com/sqeimfN.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://i.imgur.com/vKhOkQy.png";
    }
}
```

```
function toggle6(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
    imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/KRWF5TC.png">';
    }
    else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/MwtTO3w.png">';
    } }

function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2").src == "https://i.imgur.com/KRWF5TC.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2").src = "https://i.imgur.com/MwtTO3w.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2").src = "https://i.imgur.com/KRWF5TC.png";
    }
}
```

```
        <a href="javascript:toggle5('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');"><img  src="https://i.imgur.com/vKhOkQy.png" width="22px" 
        alt="Hide the Disclaimer"  style="vertical-align: top; " title="Hide the Disclaimer" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  /></a>


<br>
<div class="animatedParent animateOnce" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle ;">
<div id="contentDivImg" class="animated bounceInRight"  style="  margin:5px; width: 354px; display: none ">
  <div style=" margin: 5px; font-size: 13px; font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" >Hidden Info<br>

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iHcZrbo.png" alt="Power Fists!"  style="vertical-align: top; " title="Power Fists!" />  

  </div>        
</div>
```

```
<a href="javascript:toggle6('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');"><img  src="https://i.imgur.com/KRWF5TC.png" width="22px" 
        alt="Hide the Disclaimer"  style="vertical-align: top; " title="Hide the Disclaimer" id="imgClickAndChange2" onclick="changeImage()"  /></a>


<br>
<div class="animatedParent animateOnce" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle ;">
<div id="contentDivImg2" class="animated bounceInRight"  style="  margin:5px; width: 354px; display: none ">
  <div style=" margin: 5px; font-size: 13px; font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" >Hidden Info<br>

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iHcZrbo.png" alt="Power Fists!"  style="vertical-align: top; " title="Power Fists!" />  

  </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Non Working Version Live Example: https://justinwallis.com/hideshowscript/hideshowscript2.html